# Avoid posting back when user clicks html button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I want to avoid posting back when user clicks an html button. because i want show one pop up using javascript. I dont want postback when the button is clicked.

```
function ShowEditChoicesPopup() {
    // I want to show some pop up here.
    $("popupdiv").show();
    return false;
}
```

And the markup am using is:

```
<button onclick="javascript:ShowEditChoicesPopup();"> Edit Choices </button>
```

Please suggest some idea.

Comment: That code does not do a postback.

Comment: try with <input type="button"/>

Comment: Is the code in a `<form>` element? If so, please include that in your question, as it's vital to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the below code snippet.

```
<button onclick="javascript:return ShowEditChoicesPopup();">
```

OR

```
<button onclick="javascript:return ShowEditChoicesPopup(); return false;">
```

OR

```
<button onclick="javascript:ShowEditChoicesPopup(); return false;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply `event.preventDefault();`

```
 function ShowEditChoicesPopup(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

    $("popupdiv").show();

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function ShowEditChoicesPopup() {
     // I want to show some pop up here
     $("popupdiv").show();
        return false;
     }
    return false;
}
```

You need a second `return false` for `ShowEditChoicesPopup()` which should cancel form submission. This assumes the code is in a `<form>` block.

Comment: You're returning `false` **outside** of the scope of `ShowEditChoicesPopup()` ?

Comment: Yes, since the `return false` in `.show()` only returns false back to `ShowEditChoicesPopup()` context, which is not going to stop the postback.

Comment: Should you not rather have `event.preventDefault();` to stop it?

Comment: It's the same thing really, either `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` will have the same result i.e. no postback.

Comment: event will not be available in some cases. when i am calling from onclick. some browser will not have event as a global but chrome does..

Answer (score 0):

Use event.preventDefault(); which will prevent default behaviour of the element and performs specified function

Answer (score 0):

Follow the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/guinatal/ct8uS/1/

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <button onclick="return ShowEditChoicesPopup();"> Edit Choices </button>
    <div id="popupdiv" style="display:none">popupdiv</div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function ShowEditChoicesPopup() {
     // I want to show some pop up here
     $("#popupdiv").show();

    return false;
}
```